# sorting of objects in memory mapped file

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-mapped-files, solaris-10

I have a structure as below:

```
struct XX
{
   int x;
   char szT[200];
   int y;
} ;
```

I have a file that stores several of these `XX` objects, written through `fwrite` call. Now when I read the file as a memory mmaped file using mmap, I use as:

```
// sz = size of the file in bytes
// fd = file descriptor of the file opened through fopen in O_RDWR mode
char *p = (char *) mmap(0,sz,PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd,0);
unsigned int N = (sz / sizeof(XX)); // number of objects
```

Thus, if I have `N` objects of type `XX`, I may access the first object as:

```
XX *px = (XX*) p;
```

And, `i-th` object I can access as `px + i` where `i <= N`.
May I use `std::sort` to sort the contents of a memory mapped file being accessed as px being the pointer of first record, and `px+i` pointing to `i-th` record. 
I don't like to store `px, px+1, px+2` etc in a vector of `XX` pointers as `vector<XX*>`, as I can access the records directly from the memory-mapped file.
Please suggest.

Comment: *_etc in a vector of XX pointers as vector<XX*>, as I can access the records directly from the memory-mapped file. Please suggest._*


Confused by this. If you want to use std::sort you're going to have to use one of the standard library data structures, or create your own by the spec of the STL.

Comment: If I use a vector<XX *> as v, then I may use std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comparexx), but when I have a memory mapped file, how do I sort using custom compare function for X comparison?

Comment: Right. I see what the issue is. Use a lamda. As stated below by @Basile Starynkevitch the std::sort function optionally takes a std::function to show how you would like to sort the information.

Answer (score 3):

Read [documentation of `std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

The following compiles cleanly. It sorts a raw array with a peculiar lambda (comparing squares of numbers)

```
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <functional>

 void sort_array(int *p, size_t n) {
   std::sort(p, p+n, [=](int x, int y) { return x*x < y*y; });
 }
```

You should be able to adapt that to  your situation:

```
 void sort_xx (XX*p, size_t n) {
   std::sort(p, p+n, [=](const XX& x, const XX& y) 
    { return strcmp(x.szT, y.szT)<0; });
 }
```

Read more about [lambda expressions in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). `[=]` is a capture-list by value (actually by copy) notation (for all closed variables, theoretically the only one here being `strcmp` which the compiler is likely to optimize - so won't close it naively; probably the lambda-abstraction and its application would be inlined by an optimizing compiler).

Comment: May I ask why it is written as `const struct XX&` instead of `const XX&`?

Comment: Because an initial version of the question did not define `struct XX` properly. Fixed

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I see the edits of both the question and your answer. If you don't mind - so it's when one uses an anonymous struct that you need to define `struct` as well? I didn't know that rule.

Comment: I don't get why you're capturing `strcmp` -- isn't it the standard, globally-accessible function?

Comment: Conceptually, it is still a captured value. Practically, I believe that no closure is built at runtime (the compiler should optimize)